# unexpected "{" after @ in razor code in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razor-2

I am getting below error in render partial in razor code,  Unexpected "{" after "@" character. Once inside the body of a code block (@if {}, @{}, etc.) you do not need to use "@{" to switch to code.

```
@if (Model.Count() > 0)
{
    <div id="mReserveForTodayPartial">    
        @{Html.Partial("UpdateReserveForToday.mobile");}
    </div>
}
```

kindly help..!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Html.Partial()` return `MvcHtmlString` so you have to do like this:

```
 @Html.Partial("UpdateReserveForToday")
```

in `Html.RenderPartial()` case it writes to the output stream and that's why it's return type is `void`, so when using `Html.RenderPartial()` you have to do this:

```
@{

Html.RenderPartial("UpdateReserveForToday");

}
```

Comment: Unexpected "{" after "@" character.

Comment: this error is occuring Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Unexpected "{" after "@" character. Once inside the body of a code block (@if {}, @{}, etc.) you do not need to use "@{" to switch to code.

Comment: when I use @{Html.RenderPartial("UpdateReserveForToday");}, get error same Rush 2707

Comment: @TonyDong   was getting the same issue even after using the correct syntax and oddly enough I had to wrap the Razor code with an html tag that was local. (e.g., <div> {razor code} </div> ).

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
@{  List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
  foreach (var item in ViewData["Subcategory"] as IEnumerable<ApplicationOneStoreForEstore.Models.tblsubcategory>)     {
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem            {
      Text = item.subcategory_name,
      Value = Convert.ToString(item.subcategory_id)
    });
  }
}
```

If you have to bind DropDownList then You have to placed this code before Html.BeginForm(..)

Answer (score 0):

Below code should resolve this issue.

```
@if (Model.Count() > 0)
{
    <div id="mReserveForTodayPartial">    
        Html.Partial("UpdateReserveForToday.mobile");
    </div>
}
```

As Razor view engine can parse the code if the statements are available with in "@{ }", So in your code "@{}" is present at "If" statement so its not required to specify again.