# System.Web.HttpParseException: 'Unexpected "{" after "@" character

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm getting this exception while trying to render PartialView. When I change `@{Html.RenderPartial("_ChildReplies", parRep.ChildReplies);}`
to
`@Html.Partial("_ChildReplies", parRep.ChildReplies)`  still getting same exception.

```
@model List<Reply>

@using YourPlace.Models

<ul>
@foreach (var parRep in Model)
{
    <li>
        Author: @parRep.AuthorName
        Comment: @parRep.AuthorName
        <div>
        @{Html.RenderPartial("_ChildReplies", parRep.ChildReplies);}
        </div>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27779516/unexpected-after-in-razor-code-in-mvc4

Answer (score 0):

The code above looks **correct**... if you are getting this error, it is probably because something is going wrong inside *_ChildReplies* partial view which you have not shown in your question...

---

[Good explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980823/html-renderpartial-syntax-with-razor/6980974#6980974):

> - RenderPartial() is a void method that writes to the response stream. A void method, in C#, needs a ; and hence must be enclosed by
>     { }.
> - Partial() is a method that returns an MvcHtmlString. In Razor, You can call a property or a method that returns such a string with just a
>     @ prefix to distinguish it from plain HTML you have on the page.

So you need to either use this:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_ChildReplies", parRep.ChildReplies); }
```

Or this:

```
@Html.Partial("_ChildReplies", parRep.ChildReplies);
```

Comment: Thanks. I checked _ChildReplies PartialView and indeed there was a source of  error. I wrapped '@{ Html.RenderPartial("_ChildReplies", parRep.ChildReplies); }' in 'if block' so simply removing '@' fixed the problem.